# Why does "hexdec" produce different results?

Tags: php, hex

Have played with hex values in PHP, but haven't understand this behavior yet

```
echo hexdec(0x80); //296
echo hexdec((string)0x80); //296
echo hexdec("0x80"); //128
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`hexdec()` assumes its’s getting a string. In the first you’re taking a number `0x80`, which is `128` in decimal, and giving it to it. This means it needs to be made into a string `“128”` because the default way to convert is the decimal form. When you then want that to be treated as hex it will become `296`.

In the last one you actually say “here’s a string of a hex number, convert it to decimal” and the conversion is done.

Numeric literals aren’t handled as hex or dec or anything. They’re just numbers and `hexdec()` isn’t meant to be used with them. Only strings. This is where implicit conversions between types may cause issues.

Answer (score 1):

here are some differents between string in php internal and at php layer.

- 0x80 is a numberic literal, it is same at the internal and language layer. it is 128 hexadecimal, convert to decimal is 296.
- (string)0x80 looks like it will change to "0x80", but if you `echo (string)0x80` it will output 128!!!  and we know 0x80 is in Decimal is 128, so (string) action just change it to decimal string expression.
- "0x80" is real string expression. it will calculate every charater to hex, so it will be (0 * 16 + x * 16 (igonre) + 8 *16 + 0 * 16) = 128.

all above is the numberic in php literal final store as decimal.

(string)number  is also store decimal string expression.